# Image is hidden by css :before pseudo-element unless opacity is different than 1

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I tried to set a background color for an image by using a css pseudo-element:

```
<div class="my">
    <img src="http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/123rf-jan.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```css
img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.my:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    background: rgb(0,255,255);  
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The only way I managed to make it work is by setting `opacity:0.99;` or any other value which is not 1. I tried playing with the z-index with no success. This happens in Chrome as well as in Firefox.

Setting `opacity` to one or leaving it to be default causes the pseudo element to hide the image.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfYnu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to position the image as well:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/zfYnu/1)

Setting `opacity` to be less than 1 causes the image to create its own stacking context. This causes the image to stack itself on top of the `:before` pseudo-element which you have positioned. If you leave `opacity` as the default value of 1, this doesn't happen which causes the `:before` pseudo-element to stack on top of the image instead.

See the [CSS Color level 3 module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) for information on `opacity` and [section 9.9 of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) for details on stacking contexts.

Comment: Thanks. Not very intuitive... So why positioning the image solves it?

Comment: I don't understand why a `::before` pseudo element that is positioned absolutely would be stacked on top of its original element that is also positioned absolutely. Or, wait, does the pseudo element count as a _child_ of the div?

Comment: Anyway, I agree with Xyand that the thing with the opacity is not very obvious. I wouldn't have begun to guess that opacity<1 puts an element in a new stacking context.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Yes, it's a child. And agreed on the stacking context bit; it's actually an unfortunate side effect of how `opacity` was designed to be implemented.